# Routing path prefix Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

This question is more a curiosity rather than an actually problem (I think).

So I created a controller that has 2 functions, index and gen_seeds. When I was making the routes for each of them I did the following:

```
resources :seeder, only: [:index] do
  collection do
    get 'gen_seeds'
  end
end
```

Which is working fine. The verb, the URI pattern and the action are correct. What just got my curiosity was the prefix. The prefixes are:

```
gen_seeds_backoffice_seeder_index
backoffice_seeder_index
```

And I wonder why both prefixes have index in its name. If I add any other function will also have the index as the last prefix name. What I was aiming for was just

```
gen_seeds_backoffice_seeder
backoffice_seeder
```

But I do realize that is not really relevant for the application to work, which it does. But yeah curiosity got the better of me. Anyone knows why this happens? It might be a mistake by me since I'm still new to Ruby on Rails.

EDIT -- 
Sure here is my route file

```
namespace :backoffice do
delete :teams, to: 'teams#destroy_all'
resources :teams, only: [:index, :new, :destroy, :create] do
  collection do 
    post :import 
  end
end
resources :players, only: [:index, :destroy]
resources :seeder, only: [:index] do
  collection do
    get 'gen_seeds'
  end
end
```

end

And here are my routes

```
backoffice_teams                  DELETE /backoffice/teams(.:format)            backoffice/teams#destroy_all
import_backoffice_teams           POST   /backoffice/teams/import(.:format)     backoffice/teams#import
                                  GET    /backoffice/teams(.:format)            backoffice/teams#index
                                  POST   /backoffice/teams(.:format)            backoffice/teams#create
new_backoffice_team               GET    /backoffice/teams/new(.:format)        backoffice/teams#new
backoffice_team                   DELETE /backoffice/teams/:id(.:format)        backoffice/teams#destroy
backoffice_players                GET    /backoffice/players(.:format)          backoffice/players#index
backoffice_player                 DELETE /backoffice/players/:id(.:format)      backoffice/players#destroy
gen_seeds_backoffice_seeder_index GET    /backoffice/seeder/gen_seeds(.:format) backoffice/seeder#gen_seeds
backoffice_seeder_index           GET    /backoffice/seeder(.:format)           backoffice/seeder#index
```

Comment: Can you include more of your routes file? Adding `rake routes` will also help

Comment: Do this in your routes  get 'gen_seeds', on: :collection .
Remove collection do .. end block and place the above code .

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try `sp1rs`'s solution with a singular [resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources):

```
#config/routes.rb
resource :seeder, only: :index do
    get :gen_seeds, on: :collection
end
```

EDIT - reading singular resources documentation, it might not be what you're looking; but could help you either way

I had this exact problem with another app I was doing. The problem was the name of the route -- I had `resources :posts` -- that would show `posts_index_path` etc. Whereas if I used `resources :post`, it would change the path names to suit

Comment: Hi. I've tried the solution but the outcome was the same, it still has that index associated with.

Comment: Whar are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Instead of the naming been gen_seeds_backoffice_seeder_index I thought it should be only gen_seeds_backoffice_seeder because with the index it seems it's associated with the index which is not true